# How to send and receive html code through xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, json, soap

I have a simple html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> This is a new paragraph!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any ways to send and receive this through soap xml or through json in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ library to send or recieve json object.

build your json object as,

```
JSONObject locationInfo = new JSONObject();

locationInfo.put("HTML", myHtmlString);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it. Does it work in android eclipse project rather than android studio?